# Does the Little Evie improve the action skill cooldown rate if an enemy is killed with it while the action skill is activated?

Tags: borderlands-2

One of the [Little Evie](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Little_Evie) unique pistol's effect is: "*Killing an enemy increases action skill cooldown rate by 12%*".

I was wondering if it also increases action skill cooldown rate similar to the Gunzerker / Salvador's skill, [Get Some](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Get_Some):

> Get Some - Effect:     Shooting an enemy decreases Cooldown on Gunzerking. This effect can only occur once every 3 seconds.
>
> Gunzerking does not need to be in cooldown to trigger this skill. It can cooldown the ability while Salvador is Gunzerking.
>
> With 11 points in Last Longer, and 5 points in Get Some, it is possible to completely reset the cooldown of Gunzerking several seconds before the duration finishes, assuming Get Some is triggered constantly. This allows Salvador to stay Gunzerking for practically an entire raid boss fight, maintaining all Gunzerk-only benefits such as Ain't Got Time to Bleed and Bus That Can't Slow Down.

If an enemy is killed by the Gunzerker *while* Gunzerking with the Little Evie, will it also decrease (or even completely reset) the cooldown of Gunzerking? What about with the other characters? (especially Gaige, who I'm planning to also use this gun with)

Comment: I believe that it will decrease (or completely reset)the cool down of your gunzerking. The game makers probably made it this way as the Little Evie is a shock weapon and thus, it does little damage to your enemy once they no longer have shields.

Comment: I'd assume it does not work this way. If you think about it, Get Some *adds* some cooldown value each time it procs (I believe Buzz Axe Rampage cooldown bonus from receiving damage also works when BAR is active), while other skills and relics modify *cooldown speed* by a percent, and do not work when skill is active. What I'm trying to say is, when a skill is active, its *cooldown rate* is zero, so +12% is applied to zero and does not add much :)

Comment: No test data though.

Comment: From looking at the code, the Little Evie simply subtracts ticks from the cooldown meter, while Get Some will simply increase the cooldown rate by a flat amount. This means that the Little Evie will NOT trigger skills like Keep It Piping Hot.